# Return statement for unit conversions

Tags: python, function, loops, return

I am creating a menu for unit conversions and need to use a `return` statement. I am not too sure how to use the `return` statement properly because when I try writing it in my code it does not work.

```
# Print menu
def print_menu():
    print('I. meters to kilometers')

# Create a function to return value
def m_kilo():
    m=float(input("Enter meters to kilometers: "))
    kilo = m *.001
    print('Distance in kilometers: ')
    return

print_menu()
choice = input("Enter conversion option: ")
if choice == 'I':
    m_kilo()
```

Comment: Where is print_menu() defined?

Comment: `return` returns a *value*. You aren't specifying one, so the function just returns `None` instead. I suggest reading about functions in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions.

Comment: @chepner but they're not trying to *use* the return value, so it shouldn't matter.  The function itself is providing the output.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what "does not work" means?

Comment: @MarkRansom It could, but it's not. If the intent is to print the conversion in the function itself, then no `return` statement is needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I added value to the return statement and printing the output. Is this what you are looking for?

```
def print_menu():
      print('I. meters to kilometers')
def m_kilo():
  m=float(input("Enter meters to kilometers: "))
  kilo = m *.001
  print('Distance in kilometers: ')
  return kilo

print_menu()

choice = input("Enter conversion option: ")

if choice == 'I':
   print(m_kilo())
```

output

```
I. meters to kilometers
Enter conversion option: I
Enter meters to kilometers: 10
Distance in kilometers: 
0.01
```

Comment: Hi Shreyas! Yes, thank you!!